# Use MapBox Satellite basemap in ArcGIS Online web map

Tags: arcgis-online, mapbox, arcgis-online-basemaps

I want to add the MapBox Satellite basemap layer as an option in my ArcGIS Online web app.  There is a widget that allows users to toggle between basemaps and I would like MapBox Satellite to be an option there.  Is this possible?  I know the URL JOSM is using to display it is this:

`tms[19]:http://{switch:a,b,c}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/openstreetmap.map-inh7ifmo/{zoom}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoib3BlbnN0cmVldG1hcCIsImEiOiJncjlmd0t3In0.DmZsIeOW-3x-C5eX-wAqTw`

Is there anyway to tweak this so I can use it within the basemap widget?
[Here is the map I want to use it in.](https://wvc-ut.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=a49389a9429a4b1a9412d627d0bc47e1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This link](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/04/01/using-stamen-and-mapbox-tilesets-as-basemaps-in-arcgis-com/) demonstrates how MapBox can be added as a basemap in a webmap. As cbunn mentioned, save the webmap with just the basemap. Share the webmap with a group that will be used for basemaps. Then change the organisational basemaps to use that group as below (any groups that you have in your organisation will appear):

[image]

When you select a group that is not default, an option appears to add the Esri basemaps to the group. Note that all basemaps in the group must have the same spatial reference. And don't ask me about licencing!

Answer (score 2):

If you are the admin in the org you can add that basemap to your basemap gallery. To do that you would save a web map with the mapbox imagery layer as the basemap. Then share that web map to the basemap group in your org and when you are configuring the basemap widget you can set up the basemap widgets to display all the basemaps you wish to show or not.